# .NET deployment using azure devops pipeline : dll file version don't match

Tags: dll, devops

I have a .net project using dotnet 6.

I try to create a pipeline using azure devops through a self-hosted agent. Thus, I have Azure Devops where are stored my code and i have a windows server as a VM where i want to deploy my project.

All work well on my local machine.

The pipeline works too. All project are compiled. But, when i launch the project in IIS, it fails.
When launching through command line, i have these errors:

```
    2023-04-04 08:55:36 [Fatal] Api stopped unexpectedly "mardi, 04 avril 2023 08:55:36"
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, Version=6.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)
```

And I found these differences of version for dlls between my local machine (left) and the deployment machine (right):
[DLL on my local machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZ9dU.png)
[DLL on my deployment machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lc4b7.png)

I try to add libraries in GAC : `.\gacutil.exe /i "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\APP\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll"`

And I write redirection binding in app.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="6.8.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>

</configuration>
```

But nothing works...

How get rid of of these errors ?

Thx a lot for your help !

Comment: I found my problem ! I have 4 projects and same DLLs exists in severals projects but with different versions. So, when i extract these 4 projects zip, recents DLLs were erased by older DLLs...

Comment: But I don't understand why app.config don't work...